# Safari - How To Automate The Reset Safari Items

Tags: safari, reset

Using Safari browser and finding one hurdle to making it my default browser - there is no default setting for clearing/deleting all the stuff you find in the menu's Reset Safari panel.

I made an Automator routine using the 'Watch Me' to do this and quit safari - it works. But, I'd really like to not have the steps display while it's running. The show actions is not selected but, they still show.

I tried creating a script but Safari dictionary does not have the option for Reset (or any of the reset panels items...)

So, how can I accomplish this?